# Why postprocessing is extremely slow on mobile devices?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, opengl-es, unreal-engine4

Postprocessing on the mobile device is slow and not preferred, everybody knows this fact.

I'm curious about why they run slowly especially on mobile devices. Because of overall performances except PostProcesing are totally fine.

Here are two benchmarks 
(3DMARK on 960m) https://www.3dmark.com/is/4046873
(3DMARK on iPhoneX) https://benchmarks.ul.com/hardware/phone/Apple+iPhone+X+review

960m got a 220,547 on a graphic, iPhoneX got a 111,322.
Basically, there is just 2x times difference. 
(I know this comparison is not wise, but what I want to say is modern mobile device has good performances, and fast enough to render 3D scenes)

In my experience in game devs, rendering 3d objects does not bother me in most times, but PostProcessing is always the hardest part. Especially shaders which use near pixels such as Bloom and Blur.

So, my question is,
Is there any architectural differences between PC and mobile particularly on PostProcessing?

Answer (score 0):

PostProcessing often uses screen-space shaders that are heavy on the GPUs of mobile devices. On top of that, mobile devices much larger resolutions (which means lots of pixels the shader has to process) than they could actually support in a game.

One way to enhance the performance of screen space shaders is to virtually limit the resolution by using a low-res RenderTexture as it greatly reduces the amount pixels that have to be processed by the shader.

Understanding shaders can help you understand why they're so expensive on some platforms. I recommend reading this: https://thebookofshaders.com/